# Publishing to Moodle forum via email

Tags: email, moodle, forum

In Moodle 4.0, can I publish a message to a course forum (a course that I teach) without logging into my Moodle account, that is, by sending an email to some pre-specified address associated with the forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reply to a forum post via email but the admin will need to set up the Moodle site to receive incoming emails

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Using_Forum#Reply_to_posts_via_email

Then maybe create a pinned forum topic, subscribe your students to it, then reply via email

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Using_Forum#Pinned_posts

Comment: So there is no way to start a new topic by email - only reply to an existing topic?

Comment: Not that I know of, that would be custom development. There are a handful of forum plugins, maybe check if they have that functionality. https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=forum%20type:mod

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if the admin has the setup configured in mail configuration settings (Site administration -> Server -> Email.)